Django Admin: How to hide nested inline until parent is saved?
I'm using django-nested-admin
I have a nested inline setup in Django Admin where I want to hide a child inline until its parent is saved. Here's a simplified version of my models:
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Component(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ComponentSetting(models.Model):
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

And here's my admin setup:
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline

class ComponentSettingInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = ComponentSetting
    extra = 0

class ComponentInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Component
    extra = 0
    inlines = [ComponentSettingInline]

class ProductAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ComponentInline]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)

Current Behavior

When editing a Product, I can add Components
The ComponentSetting inline is visible immediately when adding a new
Component
I want the ComponentSetting inline to only appear after the Component
is saved

Desired Behavior

ComponentSetting inline should be hidden when adding a new Component

ComponentSetting inline should only appear after the Component is
saved

ComponentSetting inline should be visible when editing an existing
Component


What I've Tried

Override get_inlines() but it does not work, because on nestedInlines it's called once when the page is loaded, so we can't adapt its behaviour regarding the parent is created yet or not

Using the template property to return an empty string or empty template

Using has_add_permission and get_queryset

Checking for parent instance existence


None of these approaches fully work - either the inline is always visible or always hidden.
Question
How can I properly hide the nested inline (ComponentSetting) until its parent (Component) is saved?
I'm using:

Django 4.2
django-nested-admin
Python 3.10

Any help would be appreciated!

So it is about the ComponentSettingInline, if the Product exists?

No it's showing ComponentSettingInline if Component is created or exist and in its oposite case, hidding ComponentSettingInline until the Component is created @willeM_VanOnsem
